# Vue.js how to use radio buttons inside v-for loop

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to use radio buttons, so that users can choose one of the photos as their profile photo:

```
<ul v-for="p in myPhotos">
  <li>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          photo id: {{p.imgId}}
        </div>
        <input type="radio" v-model="profileImg" value="p.imgId"> Choose as profile image
      </div>
      <div><img v-bind:src="BASE_URL +'/uploads/' + userId + '/'+ p.imgId" /> </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The values are otained like this:

```
created () {
  axios.get(this.BASE_URL + '/profile/g/myphotos/', this.jwt)
  .then( res => {
    this.myPhotos = res.data.photos;
    this.showUploadedPhoto = true;
    this.profileImg = res.data.profileImg
  })
  .catch( error => {
    console.log(error);
  })
},
```

When an photo is chosen, the `profileImg` variable should be set to that photo's imgId.

The problem is how to let users to choose only one photo as profile image inside this v-for loop?

Update: a photo my `myPhotos` object that I'm iterate over:

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

By providing name you can treat it as one element

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
    images:[{imgId:1},{imgId:2},{imgId:3}],
    profileImg:2
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<div>
  <div v-for="image in images">
              <input type="radio" v-model="profileImg" name="profileImg" :value="image.imgId"> Choose as profile image
  </div>
  You have selected : {{profileImg}}
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you share a snippet like us and share what exactly not worked ?

Comment: @Babr : As you said , here you can select only one image at a time . not ?

Comment: Yes, I want to select only one image at a time, but also want to assign its value `profileImg` when it is clicked.

Comment: yes if you run code snippet you will see `profileImg` as updated

Answer (score 1):

How about setting `name` attribute for the input field

```
 <ul v-for="p in myPhotos">
    <li>
      <div>

      <div>
        <div>
          photo id: {{p.imgId}}
        </div> 
          <input type="radio" name="user_profile_photo" v-model="profileImg" :value="p.imgId"> Choose as profile image
      </div>
        <div><img v-bind:src="BASE_URL +'/uploads/' + userId + '/'+ p.imgId" /> </div>
    </div>
      </li>

  </ul>
```

Comment: Well this helps to choose a single item but how to set `profileImg` to `p.imgId` when a certain item is clicked?