# How to bind radio buttons to containers using v-for?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have been trying to build a quiz with Vue js but am running into the problem right now where the radio buttons are not getting bound to the questions like I want: https://jsfiddle.net/deeformvp/sqx3m2bz/2/

```
<div v-for="(question, index) in questions" :key="index">
    {{question.question}}
    <div v-for="(answer, index) in question.answers" v-model="pricingUnit" :key="index">
       <label>
        <input type="radio" name="question.question">{{answer}}
       </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

All the answers seem to be working together instead of separated by question div. What am I missing?

I have taken a look at [Vue.js how to use radio buttons inside v-for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52943097/vue-js-how-to-use-radio-buttons-inside-v-for-loop) and ensured that I bound the name variable but it still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo: `name` should be `:name`:

```vue
<input type="radio" :name="question.question">
```

Comment: I HATE THAT I MISSED THIS AND YOU ARE RIGHT THANK YOU SO MUCH